# sed replace entire line matching string containing '/' and spaces replacing it with another string

Tags: sed

I am struggling with this problem and have tried multiple answers I looked at (Google / stackoverflow).

Using bash script, I want to replace:
`image: quay.io/repo/someimage:sometag`
with
`image: quay.io/repo/someimage:newtag`

Keeping in mind the following:

1. There are leading spaces before "image" which I don't want to lose.
2. I do not have the old image tag name so I cannot just replace the tags.

My shell script is something like:

```
TEXT="image: quay.io/repo/someimage:"
TEXT_NEW="image: quay.io/repo/someimage:${TAG}"
sed -i "s|$TEXT .*$|$TEXT_NEW|g" "docker-compose.yml"
```

I have tried multiple approach here but none worked or partially worked:
This does work partially but for some reason it just appends the new TAG to the old TAG. Does not replace it.

```
sed -i -e "s|image: quay.io/repo/someimage:*| image: quay.io/repo/someimage:${TAG}|g" docker-compose.yml
```

This throws an error. I am guessing due to '/'.

```
sed -i "/image: quay.io/repo/someimage:/c image: quay.io/repo/someimage:${TAG}" docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: Your first example works, if you remove the extraneous space: `sed -i "s|$TEXT.*$|$TEXT_NEW|g" "docker-compose.yml"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly but the space was the problem:

```
sed -i -e "s|$TEXT.*|$TEXT_NEW|g" docker-compose.yml
```

Thanks to @Beta for the comment.